# Extract workspace that there is no data entry more than one month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Timesheet` with these columns:

```
IDWORKSPACE | DTDATE | workeddays
```

And another table `TWorkspace`:

```
IDWORKSPACE | TYPE | NAME
```

How could I extract all workspace names that there is no entry data for worked days for more than one month?

Comment: Sample data, expected results ***and** your* attempts will help us help you. What you asking here is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check if this works:

```
select *
from TWorkspace
where IDWORKSPACE in(
    select IDWORDSPACE
    from Timesheet
    where DTDATE >= dateadd(mm, getdate(), -1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code prints records in `TWORKSPACE` table if there is no record in `TIMESHEET` table matching with `IDWORKSPACE`

```
select * from tworkspace w
where not exists (
   select 1 from TIMESHEET t
   where w.IDWORKSPACE = t.IDWORKSPACE
   group by IDWORKSPACE
   having sum(workeddays) > 30
)
```

Comment: I am looking to extract all workspace name that there is no entry data for worked days more than one month. Not those with no matching

Comment: check my edit please. I am not sure if I understand correctly. hope it helpds